# configure dovecot 10-auth.conf

Tags: authentication, dovecot

i'm going to setup mail server according this guide : 
https://workaround.org/ispmail/wheezy

on `setting up dovecot` part `10-auth.conf`

it's says change `auth_mechanisms = plain`  to `auth_mechanisms = plain login`

and it's also say's :
`By default Dovecot sets "disable_plaintext_auth = yes" which ensures that every connection is encrypted using TLS.`

but on my `10-auth.conf` file 
`disable_plaintext_auth = yes` is commented like :
`#disable_plaintext_auth = yes`

should i uncomment it ?

Comment: That depends.  Do you want every connection to be encrypted with TLS?  You need to understand the purpose of these options if you're going to configure the server.

Answer (score 0):

It's depends.
Plaintext authorization is unsafe over the outer networks where traffic can be sniffed. When auth performed over TLS connection then plaintext is ok. Also it's ok when auth take place locally on the same host. `dovecot` have neat option that allow to restrict plaintext auth over the foreign networks.

```
local AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD {
  ssl = required
}
```

All incoming connections via the interface with specified IP-address will be rejected if they are not SSL/TLS-encrypted.

Comment: if i use `auth_mechanisms = plain login` and mysql and dovecot is on same server , i should uncomment `#disable_plaintext_auth = yes` or not

Comment: Docs ( http://wiki2.dovecot.org/SSL/DovecotConfiguration ) says: _"Note that plaintext authentication is **always allowed (and SSL not required) for connections from localhost,** as they're assumed to be secure anyway. This applies to all connections where the local and the remote IP addresses are equal."_ Therefore you can leave the string commented as far it is implied by default.

Comment: But I'm still insist to define explicitly that all connections from outer space should be secured by SSL/TLS. Proposed config block is equivalent to the `exim`'s option `tls_on_connect_ports`. At least you will be protected from the password bruteforsing, cause no auth will be allowed before SSL/TLS.